# Design issue: is this doable only with producer/consumer?

Tags: java, concurrency, producer-consumer, java.util.concurrent, futuretask

I'm trying to increase performance of indexing my lucene files. For this, I created a worker "LuceneWorker" that does the job.

Given the code below, the 'concurrent' execution becomes significantly slow. I think I know why - it's because the futures grows to a limit that there's hardly memory to perform yet another task of the LuceneWorker.

Q: is there a way to limit the amount of 'workers' that goes into the executor? In other words if there are 'n' futures - do not continue and allow the documents to be indexed first?

My intuitive approach is that I should build a consumer/producer with ArrayBlockingQueue. But wonder if I'm right before I redesign it.

```
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(cores);
        List<Future<List<Document>>> futures = new ArrayList<Future<List<Document>>>(3);
        for (File file : files)
        {
            if (isFileIndexingOK(file))
            {
                System.out.println(file.getName());
                Future<List<Document>> future = executor.submit(new LuceneWorker(file, indexSearcher));
                futures.add(future);
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("NOT A VALID FILE FOR INDEXING: "+file.getName());
                continue;   
            }
        } 

        int index=0;
        for (Future<List<Document>> future : futures)
        {
            try{

                List<Document> docs = future.get();

                for(Document doc : docs)
                    writer.addDocument(doc);    


            }catch(Exception exp)
            {
                //exp code comes here.
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the number of waiting jobs, use a `ThreadPoolExecutor` with a bounded queue like `ArrayBlockingQueue`. Also roll your own `RejectedExecutionHandler` so that the submitting thread waits for capacity in the queue. You cannot use the convenience methods in `Executors` for that as `newFixedThreadPool` uses an unbounded `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the standard input size and the complexity of the LuceneWorker class, I could imagine solving this problem at least partially using the Fork/Join framework. When using JDK 8's [CountedCompleter](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166ydocs/jsr166y/CountedCompleter.html) implementation (included in [jsr166y](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/jsr166/dist/jsr166y.jar)) I/O operations would not produce any problems.